# How to improve scipy.sparse.csgraph.breadth_first_order performance?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, scipy, profile

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csgraph, dia_matrix

n = 1000
g = dia_matrix((np.ones(n), 1), shape=(n, n)).tocsr()
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(n):
        csgraph.breadth_first_order(g, j)
```

I wrote this piece of code and profiled it.

The `breadth_first_order` function spent most of the time validating the graph `g` I passed in. How do I improve the performance of this function?

Is there a way to make SciPy validate the graph only once?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the existing code, there's not much to do: You're already on the [happy path](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/6d576be2445431eee48f72b5ac59ca8e8553076d/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_validation.py#L25) where all the validation does is create a new `csr_matrix` of the same `dtype` without creating any copies.

But, if you have Cython available for your workflow, you could also skip the validation entirely and instead go straight to the underlying method, [`_breadth_first_directed`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/6d576be2445431eee48f72b5ac59ca8e8553076d/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.pyx#L355). Do note that by doing so, you lose SciPy's API stability promises, and the function could change in future versions (or be removed entirely) without notice.

Alternatively, if you don't mind monkey patching, you can simply replace the imported validation function with the identity (once again relying on implementation details); this effectively removes all validation and does indeed create the performance improvement you are looking for:

```py
In [2]: import scipy.sparse.csgraph

In [3]: %timeit scipy.sparse.csgraph.breadth_first_order(g, 0)
34.9 µs ± 315 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [4]: scipy.sparse.csgraph._traversal.validate_graph = lambda csgraph, *args, **kwargs: csgraph

In [5]: %timeit scipy.sparse.csgraph.breadth_first_order(g, 0)
8.6 µs ± 82.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

If you think this would be a useful/common use case in general, you can open an issue on the [SciPy GitHub issue page](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues) requesting a way to skip validation. Or, open up the discussion on the [SciPy-Dev mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/scipy-dev).